# what's the closed formed of this sum?

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis, bernoulli-numbers

How can I calculate the closed form of this sum?
$$\frac{1}{k} {n\choose k-1}
\sum_{j=0}^{n+1-k} (-1)^{j}
{n+1-k\choose j} B_{j}.$$
where $B_n$ is the Bernoulli sequence (defined by the exponential generating function$\frac{x}{e^x-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{B_n}{n!}x^n$)

Comment: Why do you think this should have a closed form?

Comment: Because some one send its closed form for me but I don't know how he got it . please see this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2014048/how-can-i-calculate-closed-form-of-a-sum